# How I can do a job asynchronously using Promises in React Native?

Tags: asynchronous, react-native, promise

In a React Native project, I wrote this function using `Promise` to do a job asynchronously;

```
function doEncryptionAsync(params) {
  return new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
      // Async code started
      console.log('Promise started (Async code started)');

      // The job that takes some times to process 
      var encrypted_value = new EncryptedValue(params); 

      if (true) {
        resolveencrypted_value 
      }
      else {
        reject("Error while encrypting!");
      }
    }
  )
}
```

And I call that in my Redux action;

```
export const encrypt = ( params ) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: type.ENCRYPT
    });

    // Sync code started
    console.log('Started (Sync code started)');

    doEncryptionAsync(params)
        .then((response) => {
          // Async code terminated
          console.log('Promise fulfilled (Async code terminated)');

          encryptSuccess(dispatch, response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);

          encryptFail(dispatch);
        });

    // Sync code terminated
    console.log('Promise made (Sync code terminated)');
  }
}
```

It works, but not asynchronously! My main thread seems to be blocked until `doEncryptionAsync()` returns. The line `console.log('Promise made (Sync code terminated)')` runs, but not immediately!

My output for logs is like this;

```
// OUTPUT Simulation
Started (Sync code started)                 at time x
Promise started (Async code started)        at time x
Promise made (Sync code terminated)         at time (x + 2sec)
Promise fulfilled (Async code terminated)   at time (x + 2sec)
```

My question is what's wrong with my approach to implement a `AsyncTask`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's asynchronous behavior is only relevant for IO blocking functions. Meaning, that instead of waiting for an IO function, the event loop keeps running.

Seeing as JS is single threaded, CPU bounded computations take up the thread, and cannot be done asynchronously.

Your only recourse, then, is to create a [native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html) that will do the calculation in a different thread for you, and then call a JS callback when it's done.

Comment: Oops! I unfortunately did not know that!

Comment: For your create a `native module` solution; Our encryption job is base on a JavaScript library. At all, that's the reason why we're using React Native!

Comment: While I totally get where you're coming from, there are things that just have to do with the way the platform works. It's not a silver bullet.